# How to create a String array from an input.txt file

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner, stdin

I am having trouble creating an array that reads as an argument from the command line. The first line of this file is an integer N, and the rest of this file contains strings on each line. The first integer is the size of the array. I have successfully allocated the array, however i cannot get it to read the entire line of the input.txt file.

Here is an example of the input.txt file:

```
4
hey, 03982
bye, 30980324
no, 3290823
yes, 30948432
```

Here is a snap of my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Arrays;

class databaseSearch{

public static void main( String[] args ){

    Scanner sc = null;

    // if no arguments are entered, print out 
    // error message and correct way to invoke program
    if(args.length == 0){
            errorMessage();
    }

// Try and open the first argument on the command line
    try{
        sc = new Scanner(new File(args[0]));
    }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        errorMessage();
    }


int arraySize = sc.nextInt();
sc.nextLine();
String[] DB = new String[arraySize];
for( int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++ ){
    DB[i] = sc.nextLine();
}



    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(DB));

}

// errorMessage()
// prints out an error message with correct with to invoke program
// terminates after instructions are given
static void errorMessage(){
    System.err.println("Please try again by running the program along with a correct file.");
    System.exit(1);
}
}
```

Comment: What is the business variable? This example is impossible to verify, try to run it in a debugger to see the outcome step by step. And what is correct?

Comment: fixed it, should have been DB.length

Answer (score 0):

Your outside while loop looks unnecessary and dangerous as you know the structure of the file. Instead get your scanner, get the first int from the file, create your array with that int, and then loop that number times, that's it.

Pseudocode

```
get scanner for file
read in first int, call it arraySize. Note that nextInt() does not get the end of line token
get nextLine from scanner **and discard it** to handle the end of line token
create a String array arraySize length.
for int i goes from 0 to less than arraySize
   get a line from the Scanner
   put line in your String array
   //  Split the line using String split. // not sure if this needs to be done
end for loop
close scanner
```

Side note: You will want to learn and use Java naming conventions, including giving variables and methods names that start with a lower-case letter, and giving classes names that start with an upper-case letter. Following these rules will allow you to create code that others (us!) can follow much easier.

e.g.,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    if (args.length == 0) {
        // !! exit/error
    }

    String filePath = args[0];
    String[] lines = null;

    // use try with resources so that the resource, here the Scanner
    // gets closed when done being used.
    try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File(filePath))) {
        int arraySize = scan.nextInt();  // get first int
        scan.nextLine();  // swallow the end-of-line token
        lines = new String[arraySize];
        for (int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
            lines[i] = scan.nextLine();
        }

        System.out.println("Display results:");
        for (String line : lines) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: so what i did was i made the array a global variable, so it could be run from anywhere in the program, the loops run fine, it's just not filling my array with the content I need to fill it with. if i change nextLine() to Next(), it takes the first token of the second line and fills the entire array with only that

Comment: @sartar: try my recommendations above. Also, we have no knowledge of global/local, since this is not information that you've shared with us. If this were my program though, and if I were reading in the array in a method, I'd make the array a **local** variable and have my reading method **return** the completed array.

Comment: I guess so I don't really need my while loop and if statement in the first few lines?? I just thought that was necessary to even initially open and read the .txt file.

Comment: @sartar: whatever for? A while loop is used whenever you need to repeat something, but you don't know in advance how many times you need to repeat it. Where does that come into play here? You know how many times to loop as soon as you read the first integer.

Comment: okay, I will try your psuedo code right now. Also, in the .txt file, since the first number is an integer, and the rest are strings, does the compiler read the integer as a string, requiring it to be parsed??? or will it recognize the integer, and the strings as different things

Comment: @sartar: the compiler has nothing to do with this. The Scanner will read what you tell it to. I would have it get `nextInt()` to start with, and then call `nextLine()` but discard the line, since as I noted above, `nextInt()` does not parse the EOL character.

Comment: when i get the next line for my array in the for loop, should that be .next() or  .nextLine()?

Comment: @sartar: you should be able to answer this yourself -- what is it you want? a small partial line token or a fill line of text?

Comment: okkkaaay. This is my code, I keep getting an exception, i will put it in my original question

Comment: @sartar: what exception specifically?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:909)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1530)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2160)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2119)
 at BusinessSearch.main(BusinessSearch.java:25)

Comment: Which line is line 25 of BusinessSearch.java? is it where you call `nextInt()`? if so, it's trying to read an int, but no int is present. Show a small complete program and an accurate input file to allow us to figure out why it's wrong.

Comment: @sartar: your code works fine for me when I use the data file that you've posted. Are you sure that the text file is correct?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Files.readAllLines()`.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.charset.Charset-)

```
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(arg[0]));
if (lines.isEmpty())
  throw new IllegalArgumentException("Empty file");
int count = Integer.parseInt(lines.remove(0)); 
if (lines.size() != count)
  throw new IllegalArgumentException("Incomplete file");
String[] db = lines.toArray(new String[count]);
```

Answer (score -1):

Refer Below URL for example codes :
http://javamanikandan.blogspot.com/2015/10/reading-file-into-collection-or-array.html